# ERROR: Please install STMCubeProgrammer on the machine

Tags: stm32f7

I am trying to validate a simple code on STM32F769NI target device. After clicking 'Validate on Target' in CubeMX, i select the following options and pressok.

[image]

I get the error `please install STMCubeProgrammer`. I have installed this programmer, the path is added and i  dont understand why i am still getting this error. In ST-link, it shows the device is connected. (last image)

[image]
[image]